# How do I parse hard drive identifiers

Tags: standards, uniqueidentifier, text-parsing, hard-drive

[image]

This image shows some hard drive IDs, they look pretty standardized (acquired from a web GUI which gathered the data from the command prompt on CentOS).

Are these drive IDs standardized and how can I parse the data out (of any set of hard drives on the market). i.e. I want to end up with the following variables (would regex work for any drive on the market?):

```
type=scsi
type2=SATA
MFR=WDC
model=WDC_WD1001FALS
serial=WD-WCATR6632234
```

Is this apparent order truly standardized across all mfrs and how do I parse it?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you see comes from a `.rules` file on your computer, something like ["60-persistent-storage.rules"](http://pre-c1nn.innova.uniovi.es/debian/dists/wheezy/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/xen/Initrd/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules):

```
# by-id (hardware serial number)
KERNEL=="hd*[!0-9]",            ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", \
    SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/ata-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
KERNEL=="hd*[0-9]",         ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", \
    SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/ata-$env{ID_SERIAL}-part%n"

KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]",            ENV{ID_SCSI_COMPAT}=="?*", \
    SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/scsi-$env{ID_SCSI_COMPAT}"
KERNEL=="sd*[0-9]",         ENV{ID_SCSI_COMPAT}=="?*", \
    SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/scsi-$env{ID_SCSI_COMPAT}-part%n"

ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk",       ENV{ID_BUS}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", \
    SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition",  ENV{ID_BUS}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", \
    SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-part%n"

ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk",           ENV{ID_EDD}=="?*", \
    SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/edd-$env{ID_EDD}"
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition",      ENV{ID_EDD}=="?*", \
    SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/edd-$env{ID_EDD}-part%n"

ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk",           ENV{ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION}=="?*", \
    SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/wwn-$env{ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION}"
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition",      ENV{ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION}=="?*", \
    SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/wwn-$env{ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION}-part%n"
```

These rules [can be changed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117533).

Note that your strings are SCSI, and the rules for SCSI IDs follow [these rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/identifiers-for-scsi-devices) (although I'm not sure how exactly this works).